# pecl: command not found on macbook

Tags: php, pecl

my php version is 7.3.1 I can see the pecl is installed on my mac but . whenever I am trying to access it through the terminal, it says pecl:command not found. Please help me with the same.

Comment: How can you see it is installed?

Answer (score 39):

Following instructions install PEAR and PECL on Mac OS X under `/usr/local/`.

PECL is bundled with PEAR. So this is as simple as installing PEAR on Mac OS X.

**Download PEAR**

```
curl -O https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

**Configure and Install PEAR**

You should now be at a prompt to configure PEAR.

2. Type **1** and press return.
3. Enter: `/usr/local/pear`
4. Type **4** and press return.
5. Enter: `/usr/local/bin`
6. Press return

**Verify PEAR**

You should be able to type:

```
pear version
```

Comment: If you don't get the file, try to use `http` instead of `https`.

Comment: A small hint: You should also be in a directory with write permissions. For example in `/Users/username/`

Comment: Thanks for this. When I get to 6, I'm returned to the same prompt for the set of 1-12 options in some kind of loop. I've noted @codiga's point and am working from within `/Users/{username}/`.

Comment: Managed to get somewhere with installing `pecl` via https://tobschall.de/2019/10/03/pear-on-catalina/.

Comment: `sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar` might not work or result in unknown command error. in that case try `php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar`